# Modify and/or delete records under one transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, primary-key

I know there are many questions about the error I'm getting, but none of them in the same scenario. I need to update and/or remove several items of an object under one "transaction" with Entity Framework.

I have a list of item objects, let's call it `List<ItemObject>` and the object which can have those items - call it `SuperObject`. **ItemObjects** have a complex primary key composed of a **SuperObject**'s primary key and a serial number in that list.

*Scenario*: A user modifies some items and marks others for deletion. Then he clicks a button to save all changes. For my assignment, I need to simulate a transaction - not a good way to use EF, I know. So, I need to set States on the items and then call `ctx.SaveChanges()`. My problem is that, while updating the serial numbers, I get multiple matching primary key values (I guess), which raises the oh-so-notorious error:

> Attaching an entity of type 'ItemObject' failed because another entity
>   of the same type already has the same primary key value...

It crashes on a call to `ctx.Entry(i).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Any thoughts on how to solve this? Code given below.

```
SuperObject objWithItems = (SuperObject)Session["Super"];
List<ItemObject> itemsToKeep = new List<ItemObject>();

foreach(ItemObject io in objWithItems.Items)
                {
                    if (io.Deletion)
                    {
                        ctx.Entry(io).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                    }
                     else
                        itemsToKeep.Add(io);  
                }

                int serial = 0;

                foreach(ItemObject i in itemsToKeep)
                {
                    i.Serial = ++serial;
                    ctx.Entry(i).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            } 

                return RedirectToAction("Read", new { update = false });
        }
```

I'm pretty vanilla at this and am still getting to grips with the concepts of EF, so I can't figure out a way go around this error and still meet the demands of the assignment.

Comment: `SaveChanges` should handle all of your transactional stuff for you

Comment: @SamIam I wouldn't know, but I do know that I still get an error

Comment: the error is that some entries in io do have the same Id (or whatever the PK for that object is called) values. Either you added the same item twice or your id values are not initialized correctly. Since the Entry() method attaches the object to the context, either of those lines may cause this exceptions. IF all entries do have correct id values, the SaveChanges() call will persist the changes in the context(or the changetracker, as it will also track all relevant entries) within a single transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your context already holds the entry of your entity, so it will not allow you to add another entry of the same entity.

You need to explicitly mention ".AsNoTracking()" in your query.

Please refer to "No-Tracking Queries" from this [url](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/252/mvc-5-with-ef-6-in-visual-basic-advanced-entity-framework-scenarios)

Comment: My problem was that I misunderstood the requirements... I wasn't supposed to change the serial number as it is the part of a primary key... which was perfectly natural when I thought about it afterwards. Now this works fine, but the logic is completely different

Answer (score 2):

You can debug the issue by analysing the ChangeTracker for your context.
Before the  ctx.SaveChanges() add the following code and debug your application with the break point inside the loop.

```
        var ctxEnteries = ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries();
        foreach (var entry in ctxEnteries)
        {
            //you can inspect the value like originalvalue, currentvalue, state, etc...
            var state = entry.State;
            var entity = entry.Entity;
        }

        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

So you can exactly find the ItemObject that is causing the issue.
Easy way to debug and fix the problems related to context.
Let me know if this helps!

Comment: It doesn't get to that particular line of code. It crashes at `ctx.Entry(i).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able  to resolve my problem using your hint.